# keyring couldn't be identified for storing the encryption

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyring

I need help resolving this issue. I don't think I changed anything lately, so maybe some update caused it.  (I did switch from `lxpolkit` to `polkit-gnome`, but I don't understand how this could be an issue).

Error message:

**An OS keyring couldn't be identified for storing the encryption related data in your current desktop environment.**

Open the troubleshooting guide to address this or use weaker encryption that doesn't use the OS keyring.

Choices: "Open troubleshooting guide" or "Use weaker encryption"

The first option did nothing, so I had to choose the second.

System information (anything I can think of as relative).

Fedora 38 Workstation with sway (not the sway spin)

Some environmental variables that I guess could be relevant:

```bash
# in .profile:

eval $(/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh)
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
GNUPGHOME=/home/yiannis/.config/gnupg

# Before sway starts ():
`XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=sway`
```

The first option, "Open troubleshooting guide", did nothing, so I had to choose the second.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/187338#issuecomment-1630300049)?